# How can you convert a WebM with transparency to MP4 with a background color using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I'm trying to convert a webm file that has a transparent background to an mp4 file. Mp4 doesn't have transparency so I'm trying to using this color: #D9DADB. How can I make this conversion happen with a single command in ffmpeg?

I've tried the following command and I seem to get a black background instead of a gray one:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=0xD9DADB -i 123.webm 123.mp4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The native VP8/9 decoders don't support transparency, so a) you'll have to force a decoder, b) the way to change transparent pixels is to overlay the video onto the color.

```
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx -i 123.webm -f lavfi -i color=c=0xD9DADB,format=rgb24
       -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[bg][vid];[bg][vid]overlay=format=rgb:shortest=1,setsar=1"
       -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy 123.mp4
```

Comment: this is great - just 2 problems though. 1) the rendering doesn't stop - it can go well past the final frame. 2) the resolution is different than the original. I'm guessing its because of the pix_fmt argument? How can i set specific dimensions for the final image?

Comment: 1) corrected, 2) not because of that, also corrected

Comment: If your WebM isn't using VP8 but instead VP9, you need to replace `-c:v libvpx` with `-c:v libvpx-vp9`.